# vAxis.direction no longer working in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

My company does a handful of reports in Google Spreadsheets and have used "vAxis.direction" to change the direction of the vertical axis. When Google recently pushed in the new Charts, all charts were reverted and this option stopped working.

Curious if anyone has insights to get this working again. This was the script that was previously used:

```
function newChart() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Chart");
 var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
 chart = chart.modify()
     .setOption('title', 'this is a title')
     .setOption('vAxis.direction', '-1')
     .setPosition(4,6,0,0)
     .build();
 sheet.updateChart(chart);
 }
```

The setOption title and setPosition continue to work without issue, but vAxis.direction does nothing.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Indeed, Google broke it. There is a [related bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62511012). Given that the spreadsheet interface does not allow reversing the vertical axis (as it does for horizontal), this may be by-design.'